# Angular modules aren't working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, controller

I have an angular app that I am trying to have pull from a controller and it's not working.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="shopItemController">
<div class="itm" ng-repeat="shopItem in shopItems">
<div class="imag"></div>
<h2>{{ shopItems.name }}</h2>
<div class="hf">Buy it: {{ shopItems.price }}</div>
<div class="hff">Earn it: {{ shopItems.altprice }}</div>
<div class="desc"><div>{{ shopItems.desc }}</div></div>
<div class="prog"><div>{{ shopItems.progress }}</div></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and here is the controller

```
var shopItems = angular.module('shopItems', []);
var trophyEarns = angular.module('trophyEarns', []);
var app = angular.module('app', ['shopItems', 'trophyEarns']);

shopItems.controller('shopItemController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.shopItems = [{
            //id: 01,
            name: 'One',
            //img: '',
            price: '$3.99',
            altprice: '1 mile',
            desc: 'This is a fake description 1.',
            prog: '50%'
        },{
            //id: 02,
            name: 'Two',
            //img: '',
            price: '$3.99',
            altprice: '1 mile',
            desc: 'This is a fake description 2.',
            prog: '50%'
        },{
            //id: 03,
            name: 'Three',
            //img: '',
            price: '$17.99',
            altprice: '12 miles',
            desc: 'This is a fake description 3.',
            prog: '100%'
        },{
            //id: 04,
            name: 'Four',
            //img: '',
            price: '$17.99',
            altprice: '10 miles',
            desc: 'This is a fake description 4.',
            prog: '100%'
        }];
});
```

I don't understand why this is not working. I built this a while back and I have no idea why it stopped working. I just want the HTML to populate with the objects in the controller. I'm trying to build an angular object for my online portfolio. I have a fiddle for this as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/galnova/jrtto5kj/6/

Comment: `shopItems` is not same as `shopItem`.

Comment: Please use "shopItem.price" instead of "shopItem**s**.price".

Comment: Thanks. I still don't understand how shopItem works when it's not used anywhere. Is it because shopItem is the singular version of shopItems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your third line of the HTML, you have

```
<div class="itm" ng-repeat="shopItem in shopItems">
```

**shopItems** is the list of objects/array that you're looping through with ng-repeat. On each iteration, an individual item is then stored in **shopItem**. To make this distinction stand out a bit more, we could change your HTML quoted above to:

```
<div class="itm" ng-repeat="currentProduct in arrayOfProducts">
```

Renamed like that, it might be more intuitive that when you're trying to display a product, you would use **currentProduct.price**, **currentProduct.desc**, etc. Your code doesn't work because (using my renamed example) you're trying to display **arrayOfProducts.price** - a property that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing object with in the ng-repeat. You should access the loop instance **shopItem**

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jrtto5kj/13/)

```js
var shopItems = angular.module('shopItems', []);
var trophyEarns = angular.module('trophyEarns', []);
var app = angular.module('app', ['shopItems', 'trophyEarns']);

app.controller('shopItemController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.shopItems = [{
            //id: 01,
            name: 'One',
            //img: '',
            price: '$3.99',
            altprice: '1 mile',
            desc: 'This is a fake description 1.',
            prog: '50%'
        },{
            //id: 02,
            name: 'Two',
            //img: '',
            price: '$3.99',
            altprice: '1 mile',
            desc: 'This is a fake description 2.',
            prog: '50%'
        },{
            //id: 03,
            name: 'Three',
            //img: '',
            price: '$17.99',
            altprice: '12 miles',
            desc: 'This is a fake description 3.',
            prog: '100%'
        },{
            //id: 04,
            name: 'Four',
            //img: '',
            price: '$17.99',
            altprice: '10 miles',
            desc: 'This is a fake description 4.',
            prog: '100%'
        }];

});
```

```css
h2 { padding: 0; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; text-align: center; border-bottom: solid 1px #000; }

.itm { 
    border: solid 4px #000;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    min-width: 150px;
}

.itm div { width: 100%; }
.itm .hf, .itm .hff { cursor: pointer; text-align: center; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; float: left; width: 50%; }

.itm .hf { background-color: #ddd; }
.itm .hff { background-color: #ccc; }

.itm .desc { background: #eee; border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-top-right-radius: 10px; padding-top: 10px; margin-top: 0px; overflow: hidden; }
.itm .desc div { padding: 0 10px 10px 10px; }

.itm .prog { min-height: 20px; background: #000; border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; padding-top: 10px; overflow: hidden; }
.itm .prog div { text-align: center; color: #fff; }

.imag { background: #777; min-width: 150px!important; height: 200px!important; margin: auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="shopItemController">
<div class="itm" ng-repeat="shopItem in shopItems">
<div class="imag"></div>
<h2>{{ shopItem.name }}</h2>
<div class="hf">Buy it: {{ shopItem.price }}</div>
<div class="hff">Earn it: {{ shopItem.altprice }}</div>
<div class="desc"><div>{{ shopItem.desc }}</div></div>
<div class="prog"><div>{{ shopItem.progress }}</div></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the fiddle.

Comment: I do not see the difference. You are still using ng-repeat right?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ng-repeat. For your better understanding, you can refer this link https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-repeat.asp

Comment: I just went there. I'm sorry and am trying to learn. I think I'm doing exactly what that example is doing. No?

Comment: ng-repeat like a forloop in java script. shopItems is an array of object right. 
If you want to loop the array in JS  
for(var i=0; i<shopItems.lenght; i++){ 
var item = shopItems[i]; // This item variable will have the values of each object 
} 
same way ng-repeat also works

Comment: Thanks for the alternative approach. I understand for loops but I do not know how to change my markup to get it to work so I think I will have to stick with this method.